# Picasso: set an older version of OkHttp3

Tags: android, okhttp, picasso

In our Android App we make an extensive use of the Picasso library which uses the okhttp3 lib.

The problem is that lately okhttp3 requires minsdk 21 and our app needs to from 19 so I'd like to set an older version of the okhttp3 lib (3.12.X which support 19) when using Picasso.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Looks like Picasso is moving to Kotlin in master, so future versions might change version ranges anyway.

Comment: @Stack Diego, did it work ?

Comment: @Bhavnik yes thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this one?

```
implementation ('com.squareup.picasso:picasso:(VERSION)') {
    exclude group: 'Your OKHTTP package'
}
```

and then add your own OKHTTP version

Comment: actually I had to use the keyword "strictly" to make it work:
    implementation('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp') { version { strictly '3.12.12'  } }

Comment: Do I need to add above line along with exclude group line of code or outside of that implementation block ?